# AngularJS ng-repeat data record creation with Collapse-Expand area

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am attempting to create records repeatedly using ng-repeat and the data portion of the record need to be collapsible. I tried collapsible and working fine (I have added the script at the top of the page) but the collapsible portion is not working for the repeated records.

Can somebody tell me what I am missing ?

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
.collapsible {
    background-color: #777;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}

.collapsible:after {
    content: 'Edit';
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
    content: "Done Editting";
}

.content {
    padding: 0 18px;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
    app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $window) {
    $scope.Customers = [


                ];
 
    $scope.Add = function () {

        var customer = {};
        customer.Type = $scope.AccType;
        customer.Name = $scope.Name;
        customer.Country = $scope.Country;
        $scope.Customers.push(customer);
 
        $scope.Type = "";
        $scope.Name = "";
        $scope.Country = "";
            };
 
        $scope.Remove = function (index) {
        var name = $scope.Customers[index].Name;
        if ($window.confirm("Do you want to delete " + name)) {

                    $scope.Customers.splice(index, 1);
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
    <script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
    });
}
</script>
    
    <button type="button" class="collapsible">This is working</button>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Enter your account information:</p>
        <tr>
            <label for="ftype">Acc. Type:</label>
            <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
            <td><label for="ftype">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" value=""></td>
            <td><label for="ftype">Country:</label>
            <input type="text" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Delete"></td><br><br>
        </tr>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10">
            <tbody ng-repeat="m in Customers">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button class="collapsible">{{m.Name}}</button>
                        <div class="content">
                            <p>Notes</p>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="{{m.AccType}}" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="{{m.Name}}" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="{{m.Country}}" /></td>
                    <td><input type="button" ng-click="Remove($index)" value="Delete" /></td>
                </tr>
                
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <form>
                            <label for="type">Account Type:</label><br>
                            <input type="text" ng-model="Type" id="type" name="type" value=""><br>
                            <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
                            <input type="text" ng-model="Name" id="name" name="name" value=""><br>
                            <label for="country">Country:</label><br>
                            <input type="text" ng-model="Country" id="country" name="country" value="">
                            <input type="button" ng-click="Add()" value="Add" />
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
    <script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_summary.asp

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in very simple steps:

1. add `ng-click="isopen = !isopen"` on which you add click event.
2. add `ng-if ="isopen"` to the row which you want collapsible.

suppose you have rows like below and on clicking first `tr` tag you have to open second `tr`row. so just do it like below.

```
<table>
   <tr ng-click="isopen = !isopen"></tr>
   <tr ng-if ="isopen"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Sunny for your answer !

Comment: As I am a beginner, I could not figure out exactly how to modify the script as per your answer. This is what I tried;

Comment: `
<button class="collapsible" ng-click = "isopen">{{m.Name}}</button>
<div class="content" ng-if = "!isopen">
    <p>Notes</p>
</div>
`

Comment: @user13837193 I edited my answer. Implement and check if it is working or not

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am not sure how to implement the change to my original code. @Sunny, Could you please update it to the code I have shown above ?

Comment: Can somebody help me on this ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Thank you very much Sunny for your answer. I have been stuck for long because of this issue. Your solution works well for the problem stated. Thanks once again! There is a monor issue still remains. That is, the collapsed panel is not styled per "content" class. Any idea why it happens ?

Comment: That didn't make any difference. I am sorry to say that. Thanks for your time !